# Is there any documented study of geometry in contemporary primates ?

Tags: ho.history-overview, geometry

There are many studies of language learning abilities of primates (mostly chimpanzee, bonobo) and studies of tool use, knowledge transmission and number sense.

Are there studies or documented cases of drawing, any form of abstract graphical representation, use of concrete objects as representatives, symbols for other things not present, hints of ideal shapes such as circles or lines, uses of markings or pebbles for counting, etc ?

The less influenced by trainers and observers, the better.

Comment: This seems like a question for BiologyOverflow.

Comment: I contend that it is important for mathematics to know why and how we can do or practice mathematics. For instance to isolate mathematical results and presentation from specific biological aspects of our cognition, which can be subtle...

One way of studying this is to compare with other living species.


Comment: Hm. I smell another closure debate coming on. I too think the question is interesting, but I also think it's too far out beyond the fringes of what research mathematicians do to be suitable for MO. Anyone who strongly disagrees, please open a new thread on meta to discuss the issue. (There are two votes to close so far.)

Comment: While I agree this is an interesting question, it's a question for another site (unfortunately, I don't know which other site). For some articles about abstraction in primates, try http://scholar.google.com/scholar?q=abstract+thinking+in+primates. Note from the FAQ (http://mathoverflow.net/faq) that many other interesting types of questions, even questions more directly related to research mathematicians, are not suitable for MO. If anybody feels like closing this question is controversial, please start a thread at http://tea.mathoverflow.net.

Comment: I agree that most users of MathOverflow are not likely to be knowledgeable in this area and that a site devoted to questions about biology, or cognition or both might be a better choice, if it exists. -- I hope that if anyone here has further suggestion on where to look about this subject, he or she might leave a short comment here. Thanks.

Comment: I see the question now has two votes to reopen, so not everyone agrees with me that the question is off topic. I've started a discussion at http://tea.mathoverflow.net/discussion/397/is-there-any-documented-study-of-geometry-in-contemporary-primates/. If you have an opinion one way or the other, please join in. Discussions on meta are the way we figure out what the boundaries of MathOverflow should be!

Comment: I voted to reopen this question, since I would be interested to see a knowledgeable answer. The fact that the "average" MO user (as mentioned in the meta-discussion) or that "most MO users" are not likely to be knowledgeable about it does not seem relevant---such an objection after all would apply to most all of our questions---the right question, instead, is whether *any* MO user knows biology, and I would rather wait and see. The situation is similar to the more philosophical questions that are often closed here, even when there are MO users who can answer knowledgeably and mathematically.

Comment: @Joel: thanks for the explanation. I've copied your comment to the meta thread (http://tea.mathoverflow.net/discussion/397/is-there-any-documented-study-of-geometry-in-contemporary-primates/) and responded to it there.

Comment: I voted to reopen for the reasons given above and on meta.

Comment: @Andy: could you explain *which* reasons? As far as I can tell, the only reason given is that there isn't a better place for this question. But that's clearly an insufficient reason ... it's like arguing that we shouldn't close homework questions because the existing sites for homework help aren't any good.

Comment: @Anton: that doesn't seem like a very good analogy, because there *are* plenty of perfectly good homework help sites, whereas none of us seem to know of any site where this question would receive the attention of the relevant experts.  

Comment: Anton, my reason was that I would be interested to see a knowledgeable answer (rather than anything about whether the question would find a place elsewhere). I find the question to be at least as mathematical as questions about child-rearing, TeX or tenure.

Comment: This is not a real reference as it is pop-sci, but:
http://www.newscientist.com/article/dn16744-chimps-use-geometry-to-navigate-the-jungle.html
The cited paper is "Sophisticated Euclidean maps in forest chimpanzees" http://dx.doi.org/10.1016/j.anbehav.2009.01.025
Animal Behaviour, Volume 77, Issue 5, May 2009, Pages 1195-1201 
Emmanuelle Normanda and Christophe Boescha. This was on page 1 of a search with Google "study geometry primates", so I am not an expert. It is more about "spatial orientation" than geometry in a mathematical sense.

Comment: @Joel: Anton was also in favor of closing those threads (as was I), so citing those topics isn't really any evidence of inconsistency.

Comment: @Pete and @Joel: I've responded to your comments on the meta thread (see the comment http://tea.mathoverflow.net/discussion/397/is-there-any-documented-study-of-geometry-in-contemporary-primates/#Comment_5520). In particular, @Pete: I think this question would get more attention from the right people if it were asked at the wikipedia science help desk: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia:Reference_desk/Science

Answer (score 9):

The following is an informal response written by [Professor Laurie R. Santos](http://www.yale.edu/psychology/FacInfo/Santos.html) of Yale University.

> This is a tricky one, as there's lots of controversy on the specifics
>   related to these questions in the field of primate cognition.  On the one hand,
>   there is evidence that some primates (chimpanzees and capuchin monkeys) can use
>   some kinds of symbolic representations in some situations.  For example, both
>   chimpanzees and capuchins can be trained to use tokens to represent different
>   numerosities.  Once trained, they can do all kinds of smart things with these
>   new symbols-- including adding and subtracting them, and so on.  There's also
>   evidence that chimpanzees can understand some spatial symbols, such as using a
>   scale model of a room to figure out where a piece of food in a real room is
>   hidden.  I think this use of a scale geometric model is actually the best
>   evidence for symbol use that's really geometric in nature.  That said, it's
>   pretty limited and does appear to require at least some training to get going. 
>   To my knowledge, there are not real cases of other spontaneous kinds of
>   symbols.  There's nothing like representational drawing in primates (lots of
>   very abstract painting, but nothing that would suggest graphical
>   representations) or anything like spontaneous use of marking/pebbles for
>   counting.  So I guess the upshot is that primates can use symbols sometimes, but
>   in very restricted, very scaffolded, and often very limited ways.
>
> Here are also two references that might be of use...
>
> chimpanzee use of scale models:
>   http://www.infantcognitiongroup.com/Portals/0/PapersPosters/KuhlmeierEtAl(1999).pdf
>
> capuchin use of symbols:
>   http://www.sciencedaily.com/releases/2008/06/080610212404.htm

(ed -- note that the comments below were written about a previous revision of this answer, which was just a promise to ask Prof. Santos! Since the question is currently closed, Pete's only option was to edit this answer.)

Comment: Thanks very much Pete for your intermediation in this matter.


Comment: I'm voting this down for the simple reason that _it isn't an answer_!  It may well be a very helpful comment, and probably the best possible from MO, but nonetheless, it is not an answer.

Comment: Let's say it is a temporary placeholder for the answers Pete L. Clark contact may provide.

Comment: I have recently written to Dr. Santos.  A few upvotes to show that people wanted me to do this were useful as a stimulus.  Also this message is a placeholder for whatever answer may eventually come, in case the question gets closed again.  

Comment: Placeholders are completely unnecessary.  If Pete gets any answers from his contact, he could simply edit the original question to include a link to them.  Something along the lines of "As this question did not fit MO, anyone interested in finding out more is encouraged to follow _this link_.".

Comment: A placeholder is somewhat reasonable because after the question is closed again presumably this answer can still be edited, while a new answer couldn't be given.

Comment: @Andrew: I think you're getting a little carried away.  Whether it fits MO is the matter in contention, but what is beyond contention is (i) some people here are interested in the question and (ii) the question does not have a natural home on any other current Stack Exchange site.  So if I happen to get an *answer* from an *expert*, it seems natural to post it here.  I fail to see the harm.  

Answer (score 5):

By following links provided by contributors to the meta-discussion, I have found these two resources of interest:

[The Comparative Cognition Society](http://www.comparativecognition.org/)

and the book [Animal Spatial Cognition](http://pigeon.psy.tufts.edu/asc/toc.htm)

Reading the rather strait-jacketed Wikipedia article on Animal Cognition, the idea of Cephalopodic Mathematics comes to mind as another pursuit.